# jsonp callback not working - code included

Tags: php, json, jsonp

here i am learning jsonp and i have a little problems with a simple code ,
what i am trying to do is a simple jsonp callback but it seems to not working

here is the code:

[index.php]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" id="myJSONPCall" src="http://mySubDomain.comoj.com/jsoncall.php?jsonCallback=myCallback"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myCallback(obj) {
                alert(obj.text);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

[jsoncall.php]

```
<?php   
    $myObject = array(
        "text" => "Hello, I am data from the remote server.",
        "created_at" => "Thu May 07 21:36:12 +0000 2009"
    );

    $myJSONObject  = json_encode($myObject);

    $myJSONCallback = filter_var($_REQUEST['jsonCallback'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    print "$myJSONCallback($myJSONObject)"
?>
```

right away , nothing happen.
what exactly goes wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors ? What does the response JSON look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your function before calling the url that loads the response
just switch the order your your scripts.

```
<html>
    <head>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            function myCallback(obj) {
                alert(obj.text);
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" id="myJSONPCall" src="http://mySubDomain.comoj.com/jsoncall.php?jsonCallback=myCallback"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```